# Add multiple cart in drupal 7

Tags: rules, commerce

I am using drupal [commerce](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce) module. In my site, there are two types of products - a regular product, and a product service. The customer can add both product types to the cart.  On the Checkout page, I would like to be able to see a product total for the regular products and the product services separately.  How do I do this?